# Excluding fields in Dozer mapping

Tags: mapping, dozer, xml-configuration

Is there a way to exclude multiple fields in [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/), when source and target classes are the same?

I am using it like this:

```xml
<mapping map-null="false" wildcard="true">
    <class-a>com.abc</class-a>
    <class-b>com.abc</class-b>
    <field-exclude>
        <a>field1</a> 
        <b>field1</b> 
    </field-exclude>
    <field-exclude>
        <a>field2</a> 
        <b>field2</b> 
    </field-exclude> ....                                                   
</mapping>
```

It seems so funny to write same name when it's known that it'll always be same for all... Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 3):

*I found this post in Google, but I configure Dozer via annotations so the existing answer didn't help me.*

In order to exclude a field from mapping via annotations use
`@Mapping("this")` on the field.

<sup>Source: [Dozer, how to ignore a field with annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40117348/1429387)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
wildcard="false"
```

will do the trick. 
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/exclude.html

Comment: a more detailed answer would have been nice