# Dozer, how to ignore a field with annotation

Tags: java, mapping, dozer, java-annotations

I'm using dozer to map objects. How can I ignore (exclude) a field using annotations with dozer?

Something like:

```
    class A
    { 
       @IgnoreField
       public String someField;
    }

    class B
    { 
       public String someField;
    }

    .........................................
    B obj = mapper.map(A_obj, B.class);
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 6):

Use `@Mapping("this")`.
It will help you